# Filtering records from database using certain criteria

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I created a database with a students table

```
myStr1 = "CREATE TABLE Students (reg_no VARCHAR(15), name VARCHAR(30), email VARCHAR(30), average_mark INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(reg_no))"
         self.myCursor.execute(myStr1)
```

I then added a function to add students details to the table and would like to filter out certain records based on a criteria. The following was my code:

```
def insert_student(self,reg_no,name,email,average_mark):
           self.reg_no = reg_no
           self.name = name
           self.email = email
           self.average_mark = average_mark 
           self.myCursor.execute("INSERT INTO Students VALUES (:reg_no, :name, :email, :average_mark)",{'reg_no':self.reg_no,'name':self.name,'email':self.email,'average_mark':self.average_mark})

           self.myConnection.commit()

def get_students(self,criteria = None):
          self.criteria = criteria
          self.myCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE '{}'".format(self.criteria))
          return self.myCursor.fetchall()

 myWrapper = DBWrapper()

 myWrapper.insert_student('F17/42770/2017','Mutheu Lorraine','mutheu@gmail.com',100)
 myWrapper.insert_student('F17/3030/2015','Ron Weasley', 'ron@eie.com',71) 
 myWrapper.insert_student('F17/3031/2015','Hermione Granger', 'hermine@eie.com',71) 
 myWrapper.insert_student('F17/3031/2017','Ginny Weasley', 'ginny@eie.com',71) 
 myWrapper.myConnection.commit()

 students = myWrapper.get_students('reg_no = F17/42770/2017')
 print(students)
```

However when i run my code I only get '[]' instead of all the details of the student with the given registration number. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the formatting, the resulting SQL command is:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Students WHERE 'reg_no = F17/42770/2017'
```

The entire WHERE clause is a string, and that string does not evaluate to true for any row.

To make the criteria an SQL expression, drop the quotes. But the comparison value must be quoted so that it is recognized as a string:

```
self.myCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE {}".format(self.criteria))
...
students = myWrapper.get_students("reg_no = 'F17/42770/2017'")
```